# Excel 2013 How to assign dates to cells

Tags: excel

I'd like to assign dates to cells in a planner spreadsheet I have made.
Currently, the rows are months, the columns are days of the week, and each individual cells just have a number for the day of the month.
I don't want to display the full date in the cell, just have the cell "know" what date it is representing. One use of this could be to have the current day always highlighted in a different colour when opening the spreadsheet. Is this possible in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, the results would require to show multiple "dates" within the cell.

For January '16 for example, you would have 4 different type of dates as January has 4 Mondays (4;11;18;25). Is this what you're looking to achieve? Otherwise it is not possible to have excel figure out a single date unless you provide it with additional references in order to come up with a result.

Comment: I may not have been entirely clear with my description. What I have is a Year Planner style thing, which shows the days of the year. I have simply given the column headings day of the week names, starting at Monday in B1, Tuesday in C1, across to Sunday in H1, then repeating Mon-Sun for the rest of a month across the top row. Then the first cell in each row has a month heading, starting at Jan in A1, Feb in A2, going down to Dec in A12. The response above from teylyn looks like it will do what I want. Cheers.

Comment: Hi alanp, thank you for your reply. I found this excel template that may save you having to start from scratch. (http://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-year-planner.html)

Answer (score 0):

Enter a date into a cell. Format the cell to show the part of the date you want to see. In the screenshot, column A contains full dates in each cell. A2 and down are formatted with the custom format code shown in column C

[image]

Excel still treats the dates as the underlying full dates in formulas, even though only parts of the dates are showing in the cell.

Comment: Thanks teylyn, this is really great. I had no idea you could format dates to this extent. Haven't had a chance to fully test this approach, but looks like it will do what I want. Cheers :-)